# Safari onClick event to focus() not working in React

Tags: reactjs, safari

I have the following code below. The input is not being focused inside safari. Any idea why? This works in Chrome.

```
focusInput: function() {
  this.refs.a.focus();
}

<div>
  <input type="text" ref="a" />
  <label onClick={this.focusInput}> some icon </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try like this, according to the ref doc.

```
const focusInput = () => {
  this.input.focus()
}

return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={element => this.input = element} />
      <label onClick={focusInput}> some icon </label>
    </div>
)
```